# Problemas com CSS e jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um estilo definido para as minhas select boxs e tenho on change em select para executar o site da select box, quando uso style nao executa o onchange ou seja não vai para o site que tenho nos meus options.

```
<select  class="styledselect_form_1"  onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option value="">Número de linhas</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=5">5</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=10">10</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=15">15</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=20">20</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=25">25</option>
    <option value="Confirmatl.php?trl=30">30</option>
</select>
```

O css :

```
.styledselect_form_1    {
    background: url(../images/forms/form_select.gif) left no-repeat;
    border: none;
    border-left: none;
    color: #393939;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 7px 0 0 6px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 192px;
}
```

o script:

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.styledselect_form_1').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
    $('.styledselect_form_2').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_2" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: não consegui entender qual é o seu problema... tente ser um pouco mais claro por favor

Comment: Funciona para mim... -> https://jsfiddle.net/byc24rvr/ Podes explicar melhor o que está a falhar?

Comment: Aqui também funcionou, deve ser outro erro e ele não conseguiu explicar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no CONSOLE do navegador para ver se há alguma incidência de erro. Dependendo do erro ou até mesmo a ordem que os scripts JS foram dispostos, a tal funcionalidade não funciona.

Comment: ele esta com algum erro no plugin selectbox que esta usando! provavelmente o plugin nao esta executando o comportamento esperado.